# FastAPI Websocket messages are being queued up and only being sent at the end of the user session

Tags: python, reactjs, fastapi

For some reason, some of my websocket messages are only being sent when a session is over or right before a websocket becomes disconneted. I have connection and session management code and I'm making sure to pass around the same websocket object, even veryfying the ID as a debugging step. I am relatively new to python so I'm at my wits ends here!

The websocket send in my connect function in main class works instantly, but the in my AutogenChat the websocket call in the new_group_chat_received_message function is only being queued and not sent.

Here is my code:

**main.py**

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: Dict[str, AutogenChat] = {}

    async def connect(self, autogen_chat: AutogenChat, client_id: str):
        await autogen_chat.websocket.accept()
        logger.info(f"attempting to connect: {client_id}")  # Log when a connection is opened
        if client_id in self.active_connections:
            # Handle existing connection, e.g., close it or notify the client
            existing_chat = self.active_connections[client_id]
            await existing_chat.websocket.close(code=1001, reason="New connection made")
        self.active_connections[client_id] = autogen_chat
        await autogen_chat.websocket.send_text("connected") #this websocket send appears instantly in my client

    async def disconnect(self, autogen_chat: AutogenChat, client_id: str):
        # await autogen_chat.client_receive_queue.put_nowait("DO_FINISH")
        print(f"autogen_chat {autogen_chat.client_id} disconnected")
        self.active_connections[client_id].websocket = None
        self.active_connections.pop(client_id)


manager = ConnectionManager()



@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return "Welcome Home"


@app.get("/get-chat-id")
async def get_chat_id():
    client_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
    while client_id in client_ids:
        client_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
    client_ids.append(client_id)
    return JSONResponse({"client_id": client_id})

@app.websocket("/autogen/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: str):
    # clients[client_id] = websocket
    autogen_chat = AutogenChat(websocket=websocket, client_id=client_id, logger=logger)
    await manager.connect(autogen_chat, client_id)
    try:
        await manager.active_connections[client_id].connect(client_id)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in WebSocket connection with client_id {client_id}: {e}")  # Log exceptions
    finally:
        try:
            logger.info(
                f"Closing WebSocket connection with client_id {client_id}")  # Log when a connection is closed
            await manager.disconnect(autogen_chat, client_id)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error while closing WebSocket connection with client_id {client_id}: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**AutogenChat class**

```
class AutogenChat:


    def __init__(self, client_id=None, websocket=None, logger=None):
        self.groupchat = None
        self.websocket = websocket
        self.logger = logger
        self.client_id = client_id


        self.product_manager_assistant = autogen.AssistantAgent(
            name="product_manager",
            llm_config=llm_config,
            system_message="Your job is...."
        )



        self.ux_designer_assistant = autogen.AssistantAgent(
            name="user_experience_designer",
            llm_config=llm_config,
            system_message="Your job is to..."
        )

        self.user_proxy = UserProxyWebAgent(
            name="human_admin",
            human_input_mode="ALWAYS",
            max_consecutive_auto_reply=5,
            default_auto_reply="APPROVED",
            is_termination_msg=lambda x: x.get("content", "") and x.get("content", "").rstrip().endswith("TERMINATE"),
            code_execution_config=False,
            llm_config=llm_config,
            system_message="""A human admin. Interact with the team to receive feedback on ideas. Plan execution needs to be approved by this admin. 
           Only say APPROVED in most cases, and say TERMINATE when nothing is to be done further. Do not say others."""similarly...
        )
        try:


            self.user_proxy.set_websocket(self.websocket)
            self.user_proxy.set_logger(self.logger)

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error in processing: {e}")

    async def new_group_chat_received_message(self, recipient, messages, sender, config):
        if messages:
            content = messages[-1]['content']
            # print ("message is ")
            # print [messages[-1]]
            if 'name' in messages[-1]:
                name = messages[-1]['name']
                #if (name != "human_admin"):
                payload = {'message': content, 'sender': name}
                json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
                try:
                    print ("before trying")
                    await self.websocket.send_text(json_payload) #This websocket send is queued up and only appears in the client after the session ends
                    print ("after trying")

                except Exception as e:
                    self.logger.error(f"Error in sending websocket message: {e}")  # Log exceptions
                self.logger.info(f"Sent message from new group chat recieved: {json_payload}")
        return False, None

    async def start_group_chat(self, message):
        self.user_proxy.register_reply([autogen.Agent, None], reply_func=self.new_group_chat_received_message,
                                       config={"callback": None})
        self.ux_designer_assistant.register_reply([autogen.Agent, None],
                                                  reply_func=self.new_group_chat_received_message,
                                                  config={"callback": None})
        self.product_manager_assistant.register_reply([autogen.Agent, None],
                                                      reply_func=self.new_group_chat_received_message,
                                                      config={"callback": None})

        self.groupchat = autogen.GroupChat(
            agents=[self.user_proxy, self.ux_designer_assistant, self.product_manager_assistant],
            messages=[], max_round=12)
        self.manager = GroupChatManagerWeb(groupchat=self.groupchat,
                                           llm_config=llm_config,
                                           human_input_mode="ALWAYS")

        await self.user_proxy.a_initiate_chat(
            self.manager,
            clear_history=True,
            message=message
        )
        self.user_proxy.stop_reply_at_receive(self.manager)

    async def send_message(self, message):
        print ("sending message " + message)
        await self.user_proxy.a_send(message,
                    self.manager)
        return self.user_proxy.last_message()["content"]

    async def connect(self,client_id):
        await self.websocket.send_text("Connecting to websocket...")
        while True:
            data = await self.websocket.receive_text()
            #future_calls = asyncio.gather(receive_from_client(autogen_chat, client_id))
            self.logger.info(f"WebSocket connection established with client_id: {client_id}")
            if data:
                message = json.loads(data)
                content = message["message"]["content"]
                message_type = message["message"]["messageType"]
                if message_type == "start":
                    print("we're in start")
                    #await autogen_chat.start_single_chat(content)
                    await self.start_group_chat(content)
                elif message_type == "feedback":
                    print ("we're in feedback")
                    await self.send_message(content)
                elif content == "DO_FINISH":
                    break
```

I'm also wondering if I should invest time in understanding ayncio better, something I've seen around but havn't quite yet tried to wrap my head around yet.

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to decompose the task and check things step by step.
Or try using another web-socket client to eliminate the possibility of mistake on frontend side.

Comment: It's unclear from your question what part of this code doesn't work (you didn't specify  messages that work well and once that don't work)

Comment: @YuriiMotov done